# How to parse jsonData?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsdictionary

Hi I'm working with ResponseData Response getting fine But while I'm parsing it is showing nil.first this is my Response

```
{
"type": "1",
"item": "Order created successfully.",
"order_id": "7"
} 
{
"multicast_id": 9215180185089775977,
"success": 1,
"failure": 0,
"canonical_ids": 0,
"results": [{
    "message_id": "0:1465191236656122%86acb02ff9fd7ecd"
  }]
}
```

Here is my code

```
NSData * urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];


            NSLog(@"Response code: %ld", (long)[response statusCode]);

            NSString *responseData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSLog(@"Response ==> %@", responseData);

            if (urlData)
            {
          jsonData=[[NSDictionary alloc] init];
              jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization
                            JSONObjectWithData:urlData
                            options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves
                            error:nil];
```

How can I parse this kind of response?

Comment: What kind of problem appears?

Comment: jsonData showing Nil.But where as responseData getting above responce.

Comment: Yes I tried that one too

Comment: @Bittoo check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19526142/parsing-nsjsonreadingallowfragments?rq=1

Comment: thanks but in scenario i"m unable to parse the jsonData.

Comment: If `jsonData` is `nil` an error occurred. Pass an `NSError` instance to the `error` parameter of the `JSONObjectWithData` method. Btw: The first line to initialize `jsonData` is meaningless because it's overwritten in the next line. And the option `NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves` is also meaningless as the result is assigned to an immutable dictionary.

Comment: @Bittoo, you have an incorrect json

Comment: @Vyacheslav Thanks for the replay yes my json is not correct.I discussed with my webdeveloper he changed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your json is incorrect

```
{
"type": "1",
"item": "Order created successfully.",
"order_id": "7"
} 
{
"multicast_id": 9215180185089775977,
"success": 1,
"failure": 0,
"canonical_ids": 0,
"results": [{
    "message_id": "0:1465191236656122%86acb02ff9fd7ecd"
  }]
}
```

for example, you forgot a comma/tag or close/open paranthesis are incorrect. Try to use this:

```
 {
    "type": "1",
    "item": "Order created successfully.",
    "order_id": "7",

    "multicast_id": 9215180185089775977,
    "success": 1,
    "failure": 0,
    "canonical_ids": 0,
    "results": [{
        "message_id": "0:1465191236656122%86acb02ff9fd7ecd"
      }]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use nsurlconnection to get the jsonData.
you need the nsurlrequest to generate the request and nsurlconnection to make connection .once you made connection .there are some delegates nsurlconnectiondelegate which you can use to get the json data.and after that you easily parse the data

Comment: But what is the Problem in above code other Urls working fine with the same code.

Comment: i think you should double quote all the keys and value than it will not show the nil value .try it...

Comment: sorry if you don't mind i didn't understood any sample code

Answer (score 0):

Check your response on http://jsonlint.com/ . This shows whether you response is valid or not.

A JSON response should be a single **NSDictionary** or **NSArray**. But you have ***two dictionaries***.

To check whether your response is valid or not programmatically, use this :-

```
NSError *error;
if ([NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                    options:kNilOptions
                                      error:&error] == nil)
{
    // Handle error
}
```

If its valid you can proceed with your conversion.